# Power Resistor TO-263 in Layout (Eagle)

Tags: resistors, eaglecad, layout, power-electronics, packages

I am using this Power Resistor [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1771760.pdf) and I am trying to put it in my layout. The Problem is I can't find any .lib (TO-263  or D2PK) file in Eagle or at least a similar package.

Any Help?

Comment: Lookup library creation in Eagle. Your own library will likely be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So go make the part yourself.  If you'd done that instead of all the searching and then asking here, you'd probably have it already.

Creating parts really isn't hard, and then you know they follow whatever your conventions are.  Using someone else's part is often more trouble because vetting it is usually more work than just making your own part your own way in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @KEVS for the tipp. But i need the library for a resistor as i mentioned it.In the Datasheet you can see that in the recommended pad layout i need online 2pins and not 3. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Olin -- you should just make it yourself that said Dangerous Prototypes seem to have a DPAK package in their open library available here: http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Dangerous_Prototypes_Cadsoft_Eagle_parts_library

Specifically I'm looking at the components vreg-3pins-dpak / vreg-3pins-d2pak. Using this blindly without validating the footprint may likely backfire however so be careful.